# Well-order on infinite set with property

Tags: proof-writing, order-theory, well-orders

**The problem.**
I want to prove the following theorem:

*Let $X$ be an infinite set. Then, there is a well-order $\leq$ on X with the property: 
$$|\{ y \in X : x < y\}|  = |X|, \ \forall x \in X.$$*

**My approach**

By Zorn's lemma, there is a well-order on this set. Now I've tried to get to a contradiction by looking at the set $\{x : |\{y \in X : x < y\}|  < |X|\}$: this set has a least element because $X$ is a w.o., thus the entire set has cardinality smaller than $|X|$. Now here I'm stuck. I'm not sure if I'm taking a correct approach, or if there's another way to prove this.

Comment: Hint: It is not true that every well-order on $X$ has the property $|\{y \in X : x < y\}| = |X|$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: So I should construct one myself? I’ve tried this aswell but could’t get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Let k = |X|.  As the set of all ordinals with cardinality k,
is not empty, there is a least ordinal $\beta$, called an
initial ordinal, with k = $|\beta|.$

Map $\beta$ onto X.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I understand this. Could I do this another way? (maybe by using that $X \times \mathbb{N}$ ~ $X$)?

Comment: Perhaps by looking at the lexicographic order on $X \times \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @xzeo.  No.  I have showed how to index X.  Divide X into the upper set you described and the set of points <= x and show the upper set is what you want.  The up vote on your question was a blunder caused by hitting a hidden link and the bad design of the stack.